# Copy paste Cell inside Table under certain conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, copy-paste, vba

I have a table where I would like execute a code to automate copying cells into other cells inside a table. The important columns for this table are J,K,L. Using this picture I will help explain what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example 1]

The conditions are what are  underlined in the various colors and the results I would like the code to execute are the arrows and squares.

- Column J = Form Component Title
- Column K = Answer Title
- Column L = Sub Category
- Column M = Form Component Comments

So Under column J, The first one underlined is **"Agree - Competency"** and the cell on the right from it (under column K) is **"Basic"**. What I would like for it to do is since the cell under column K is **"Basic"**, then the code needs to look for **"Agree - Basic"** (which is on column J) and take the cell on the **right** of it (under column K) and copy paste it into column L on the same row as the cell **"Basic"** (which is under column K).

One issue with this is that **the order under Column J is not always the same and every 41 rows the data repeats itself**. For example: for the range [J1-J40] we will have "Agree - Competency" in cell J3 but on the range [J41-81] it will have "Agree - Competency" in cell J46.

*The reason it repeats itself is because every 41 rows it is a new person's data for a new entry.*

I have includes a Picture of the requested result should look like.

[image: Desired Result]

My current code is (just to insert Column L and name it Sub Category):

```
Sub CreateNewColumn()
'
' CreateNewColumn Macro
' Creates a new column between Answer Title and Form Components Comments called "Sub Category"
'

'
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sub Category"


End Sub
```

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated.